# How to get jquery above elements to run?

Tags: jquery

I have a large chunk of Jquery in an external global.js that is above any of the elements on my page.  I can't get any of the jquery to run!  It seems as though I have to put the Jquery BELOW all the elements to get it to run.

How can I keep the jquery at the top and still allow it to run?

Comment: Enclose your code in a [`$(document).ready(function(){...})` wrapper](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready).

Comment: You're making sure the global.js is after the reference to the jquery library file?  Also, how is the content for the page loaded?  How are you loading the js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are wrapping your code in a document ready handler.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  ...your code goes here...
});
```

or (shorthand)

```
$(function() {
   ...your code goes here...
});
```

Although, I would probably put the javascript at the bottom of the document anyway AND wrap it in a document ready handler.  Putting it at the bottom allows more of the page to load in parallel, delaying your javascript (which is typically single-threaded) until the end.

Comment: Do web devs usually place jquery below dom?

Comment: @Hubrid, That's what we do at my company.

Comment: @Hubrid for me it's a mixture as my pages are sometimes composed by pulling in partial views which might have their own script code. Core scripts used by everything get referenced in the header, scripts that are used but don't have other scripts depending on them go at the bottom.

Comment: @Hubrid yes, absolutely. See http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html "Put scripts at the bottom."

Comment: How do you include an external script on the bottom of a page if you can't put it in head tags?

Comment: @Hubrid just add the script tag right before the closing body tag. `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script></body></html>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your jQuery is firing before the dom is loaded.

If that is the case, you need to wrap your script in a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // code here
});
```

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Yes it is... but isn't that where people usually plac etheir jquery?

Comment: It depends @Hubrid. Placing the script at the bottom of the page ensures that all the content is loaded before the script executes, although the above does the same.

Comment: Are you including a link to the jQuery framework in your code?  Is is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I can only guess, but try putting it inside:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code
});
```

Or (just a shorter version):

```
$(function() {
    // Your code
});
```

You're most probably binding events to and running code on elements that haven't loaded at the time the JS is executed. Putting your scripts at the bottom of the page loads scripts *after* the relevant elements have loaded. Using `$(document).ready()` waits for the page to load completely before running any JavaScript.

---

If you're doing this already, check your browser's error console for any syntax errors or script 404s.